# How to structure Vue for Interactive D3 Chart

Tags: javascript, vue.js, d3.js

In this Vue component, am trying to create an interactive bar chart hover is seems to be recreating the group element every time the data is updated. If someone can tell me where the problem is because am stuck since I've tried both the general update pattern as well as nest updated pattern.

```
export default {
    name: "StatisticsUI",
    props:["reps"],
    mounted(){
      this.setOptions(),
      this.genChart()
    },
    updated(){
      this.genChart()
    },
    methods:{
          ......
        genChart(){
            const data = [
                          ["CCP",2],
                          ["ZPA",1],
                          ["ERA",3],
                          ["POS",4],
                         ]
            const svg = d3.select("svg")
            const width = svg.attr("width")
            const height = svg.attr("height")
            const margin ={left: 50, right:50, top:50, bottom:50}

            const innerWidth  = width - margin.left - margin.right
            const innerHeight  = height - margin.top - margin.bottom

            const g = svg.append("g")
                              .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`);

            const yAxis = g.append("g").attr("class", "y-axis")
            const xAxis = g.append("g").attr("class", "x-axis")

            const xValue = d => d[0]
            const yValue = d => d[1]

            const xScale = d3.scaleBand().domain(data.map(xValue)).range([0, innerWidth]).padding(0.2);
            const yScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, d3.max(data, yValue)]).range([innerHeight, 0]);

                yAxis.call(d3.axisLeft(yScale));

                xAxis
                  .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale))
                  .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${innerHeight})`)

                 let rect = g.selectAll("rect").data(data);
                 rect.exit().remove()
     
                 rect
                   .enter()
                   .append("rect")
                   .merge(rect)
                   .attr("fill", "#69b3a2")
                   .attr("x", (d) => xScale(xValue(d)))
                   .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth())
                   .attr("height", 0)
                   .attr("y", innerHeight)
                   .transition()
                   .duration(1000)
                   .delay((d, i) => i * 50)
                   .ease(d3.easeBounce)
                   .attr("y", (d) => yScale(yValue(d)))
                   .attr("height", function (d) {
                     return innerHeight - yScale(yValue(d));
                   });
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What you posted is not enough to create a [mcve]. Your question cannot be answered without one, so please create one. Namely, you're not showing where and how you're populating `data` (probably from `reps` which, again, you're not showing). Without this information we have no way of knowing how your input looks like.